# had had already read before vs. had already read before

Tags: grammar, tense, sequence-of-tenses

Situation: Warren Xxx is storytelling his *college life* to business students. The topic is the subject's collage.

> Warren Xxx: There was this collage, it had its name of teachers who were teaching it, and I was amazed at what I saw because some of the teachers were the authors of the books **I had had read before** I met them in person.

Or

> Warren Xxx: There was this collage, it had its name of teachers who were teaching it, and I was amazed at what I saw because some of the teachers were the authors of the books **I had read before** I met them in person

What I wanted to clarify is Warren Xxx had read some books first, before he saw the collage. Moreover, is it **had had read** or just **had read**?

> (With all respect, please focus on the bold letters, this is a grammar/tenses question) I maybe wrong with the grammar, that is why I'm asking it and not to damage someone else's reputation.

Comment: "Had had read before" seems ungrammatical, so it's better to use "Had read before". You can only use a single **had** before a verb. You can say **had had** if the second **had** is not a "helping verb", and that would exclude the addition of **read**.

Comment: **Collage** or **college**?  These are different things.

Comment: It's either a typo or a misstatement.  "Had had read" is not common grammar, and doesn't fit this context.

Comment: This is a transcription issue, probably. Someone put it through some kind of automatic software, and guess what? It's full of errors. Is this a collage with teachers' names and courses taught?

Comment: @Lambie, yes it is, its **collage** with teachers' names and courses. On the flip side, this topic is from his documentary film but the sentence construction is from mine(excerpt but my rephrased sentences just to test my past tenses usage accuracy)

Comment: Why would you want to make what is perfectly good and recognizable as such into a mistake?

Comment: I don't intend to do that. I just wanted to construct a sentence/grammar on my own if my tenses is correct. Pls. Take note, its not QUOTED.

Comment: @Andrew, its collage, making my stand here. Thx

Comment: If you're familiar with Spanish, "have" can mean "haber" or "tener". "Had had" arises when both meanings are used: "habia tenido" -> "had had".

Comment: Grghh. had had exists in English, too. "had had read" does not. Spanish is irrelevant, really. And actually, this question from John Arvin surprises me because his level in English is pretty high...

Comment: @Lambie, is that so... hmm maybe that is why you are a bit 'puzzled' am I right. This is the point, lets recap to make it clearer, the situation is already in the past(had#1-''had its name of teacher who were teaching it'') then I mentioned had#2- ''had had read it before I met the person.'' Overall, the ''had had read...'' came first. That is what I'm exphasizing...

Comment: Right, so you tell me: How do you form the past perfect, when one action precedes another action in the past? :)

Comment: What? I don't get your question. I maybe overly serious about this and I can't see quirks alike here...

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if this is taken from a transcript. If so, it may be that Mr. Buffett stuttered or hesitated, repeating the word **had**, which is a mistake.

Comment: It's not taken from an official transcipt. My bad, kindly see my other answer in the comment section above.